# Builder C++ : TTreeView with checkbox items

Tags: checkbox, treeview, c++builder, c++builder-xe5

I need to create a treeview with checkbox node like this image :

[image]

How to do that?

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TTreeView` component does not natively support checkboxes, but the standard Windows `TREEVIEW` control does, via the [`TVS_CHECKBOXES` style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760013.aspx):

> TVS_CHECKBOXES
>
> [Version 4.70](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298349.aspx). Enables check boxes for items in a tree-view control. A check box is displayed only if an image is associated with the item. When set to this style, the control effectively uses [DrawFrameControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162480.aspx) to create and set a state image list containing two images. State image 1 is the unchecked box and state image 2 is the checked box. Setting the state image to zero removes the check box altogether. For more information, see [Working with state image indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760017.aspx).
>
> [Version 5.80](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298349.aspx). Displays a check box even if no image is associated with the item.
>
> Once a tree-view control is created with this style, the style cannot be removed. Instead, you must destroy the control and create a new one in its place. Destroying the tree-view control does not destroy the check box state image list. You must destroy it explicitly. Get the handle to the state image list by sending the tree-view control a [TVM_GETIMAGELIST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773585.aspx) message. Then destroy the image list with [ImageList_Destroy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761524.aspx).
>
> If you want to use this style, you must set the TVS_CHECKBOXES style with [SetWindowLong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591.aspx) after you create the treeview control, and before you populate the tree. Otherwise, the checkboxes might appear unchecked, depending on timing issues.

To apply the `TVS_CHECKBOXES` style to a `TTreeView` component, you should derive a new component and override the virtual `CreateParams()` method, eg:

```
class TMyTreeView : public TTreeView
{
protected:
    virtual void __fastcall CreateParams(TCreateParams &Params);
};

void __fastcall TMyTreeView::CreateParams(TCreateParams &Params)
{
    TTreeView::CreateParams(Params);
    Params.Style |= TVS_CHECKBOXES;
}
```

To assign the checkbox states in code, you can then use the [`TreeView_GetItem()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773841.aspx)/[`TreeView_SetItem()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760091.aspx) macros to toggle a node's state image index as needed.

Alternatively, a more flexible approach is to simply assign your own `TImageList` to the [`TTreeView::StateImages`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.StateImages) property and fill it with whatever checkbox images you want, and then you can set the [`TTreeNode::StateIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNode.StateIndex) property as needed.  To react to user input on the checkboxes, use the `TTreeView::OnClick` and `TTreeView::OnKeyDown` events to toggle the `TTreeNode::StateIndex` accordingly:

```
void __fastcall ToggleTreeNodeCheckBox(TTreeNode *Node)
{
    if ((Node) && (Node->StateIndex != -1))
    {
        if (Node->StateIndex == MyCheckedStateImageIndex)
            Node->StateIndex = MyUncheckedStateImageIndex;
        else
            Node->StateIndex = MyCheckedStateImageIndex;
    }
}

void __fastcall TMyForm::TreeView1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TPoint P;
    ::GetCursorPos(&P);
    // or: P = Mouse->CursorPos;
    // or: POINTS pts = MAKEPOINTS(::GetMessagePos()); P = Point(pts.x, pts.y);
    P = TreeView1->ScreenToClient(P);
    if (TreeView1->GetHitTestInfoAt(P.x, P.y).Contains(htOnStateIcon))
        ToggleTreeNodeCheckBox(TreeView1->GetNodeAt(P.x, P.y));
}

void __fastcall TMyForm1::TreeView1KeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift)
{
    if (Key == VK_SPACE)
        ToggleTreeNodeCheckBox(TreeView1->Selected);
}
```

Comment: I have this error E2064 Cannot initialize 'const TPoint &' with 'tagPOINT'.. in this instruction "P = TreeView1->ScreenToClient(P);"?!

Comment: Up to and including XE4, `TPoint` had a constructor that accepted a `POINT` as input. In XE5, they took that constructor out, I have no idea why. So, change the `P` variable from `POINT` to `TPoint`. As `TPoint` still derives from `POINT`, `&P` can still be passed to `::GetCursorPos()`. Or change `GetCursorPos(&P)` to `P = Mouse->CursorPos`. I updated my answer.